# Error:Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

I am getting this error after updating my android studio.

this is my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'  

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    generatedDensities = []
}
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
compile project(':databaseAutoCompleteLibrary')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'milyn:opencsv:1.6'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile project(':MPChartLib')
compile project(':filechooserlibrary')
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile project(':Volley')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

please provide any solution.
I am using volley library.
Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to include the error message.

Comment: Error:Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed. this is my error message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have faced the same issue after upgrading to latest studio.

I am not sure about the root cause but what I did is

comment below line from volley build.gradle

```
apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

As I can see there many project are there in you dependencies. 
If possible comment same from all and try syncing again.

Comment: For me although , above solution resulted in successful sync but resulted in  InvalidVirtualFileAccessException : Accessing invalid virtual file: ...

Comment: Below solution by omrsin seems more suitable .

Answer (score 17):

Same thing happened to me.

I am not a Gradle expert but my solution was a little bit less drastic. I just edited the bintray.gradle file by moving the line:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

just before the `publishing` action.

This problem seems to be related with this:

https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/issues/125

Comment: +1 Im glad you posted this (only 7 hours ago)! This has been frustrating me for the last 30 mins. Not sure why the other answer has so many upvotes, makes no sense to me! Why does gradle version bumps _always_ result in a breaking change!! SEMVER people!

Answer (score 15):

This error comes from volley module, I solved this problem by doing as follows:
open volley module, find `bintray.gradle` file and change

```
publishing {
   publications {...}
}
```

to

```
publishing.publications {...}
```

then it will work just fine.

Comment: Huh, worked for me too.  But why, tho?  I thought these two syntaxes were functionally identical?

Answer (score 0):

I got this now when I introduced a circular dependency among modules inadvertently, in case some one hits it in the future.