# Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently updated my Android Studio to altest stable release and also Gradle to 2.10 but since then I am getting this error while trying to sync Gradle.

```
Error:Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
```

The `build logs` shows this:

```
…
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script …\apphome\app\libs\volley\bintray.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
…
```

and in the `idea.log`:

```
2016-04-17 14:30:30,340 [2529786]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'MyApp'. 
2016-04-17 14:30:30,358 [2529804]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79 
2016-04-17 14:30:30,360 [2529806]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79 
2016-04-17 14:30:30,362 [2529808]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'F:\Softwares\prebuilts\tools\common\offline-m2' 
2016-04-17 14:30:30,375 [2529821]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Murphy\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit4.gradle] 
2016-04-17 14:30:32,497 [2531943]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
    ...
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at bintray_axfkbvi7vsdypemi47d2wod1p.run(F:\AndroidstudioProjects\MyApp\app\libs\volley\bintray.gradle:43)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 73 more
2016-04-17 14:30:32,499 [2531945]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'F:/AndroidstudioProjects/MyApp' 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Script 'F:\AndroidstudioProjects\MyApp\app\libs\volley\bintray.gradle' line: 43
A problem occurred evaluating script.
    ...
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
    ...
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at bintray_axfkbvi7vsdypemi47d2wod1p.run(F:\AndroidstudioProjects\MyApp\app\libs\volley\bintray.gradle:43)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 73 more
2016-04-17 14:30:32,503 [2531949]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)

2016-04-17 14:30:32,504 [2531950]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-04-17 14:30:32,505 [2531951]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-04-17 14:30:32,505 [2531951]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'MyApp' failed: Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-04-17 14:30:32,720 [2532166]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-17 14:30:32,725 [2532171]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-17 14:30:32,728 [2532174]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-17 14:30:32,728 [2532174]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

I also tried by excluding the `volley` dependency from the build dependency but error still remains. Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079404/errorcannot-configure-the-publishing-extension-after-it-has-been-accessed) solution but my volley’s build.gradle doesn’t contain the specified line. I am ready to reinstall of downgrade gradle also but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve?